# Search for a pattern using a regular expression and libgit2

Tags: c++, regex, git, libgit2

I have an application which spawns a process in order to find occurences of a particular regex within a specific commit in a git repository by running:

```
git grep -G pattern revision
```

This works just fine, but the problem is that I do this in a loop and this is extremely slow. I profiled the code on Linux and the call to `__libc_fork` alone takes 94% of the run-time.

Obviously, I'd like to avoid this unnecessary overhead. To do some other git operations, I'm already using **libgit2** in my application, but I don't see a convenient way to perform a regular expression search like I can with `git grep`. I can imagine manually going through all the files associated with a commit and performing the search, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution, up to a few lines.

Am I missing a relevant **libgit2** API? Does anyone know of a quick way to search for a pattern using **libgit2**?

**EDIT** Just to clarify: in my loop, the revision is fixed, but the pattern changes.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for the revision in which certain text appeared. You can use `git log -S pattern`, or create a small shell-script that will exit `1` or `0` depending if it found whatever you are searching, and then use `git bisect` with that script.

Comment: Actually, that's not it. I have a long list of strings and I know for sure that each string appears as part of some line in some file in a particular commit. The different strings may be in different files. What I need to get is the entire line where each string appears, because I am interested in a different part of the same line. So `git grep` seems like the right tool for the job. I just need a faster `libgit2` equivalent, but I don't want to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libgit2 does not have a `git grep` equivalent, since that's nowhere near a basic Git operation. It's very high level and the actual interesting work (efficient grep) has nothing to do with Git, so libgit2 would be a bad place to put that code.

Since the issue that you see is down to forking being more expensive than anything else, I see two ways to avoid that. One is to use `git cat-file`'s `--batch` option to feed it a list of objects to show, which you can get e.g. from `ls-tree` like

```
git ls-tree -r ${revision} | cut -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | git cat-file --batch
```

which produces a machine-readable output with an `$id $type $len` triplet at the start of each file (it might be easier/cheaper to replace those `cut`s with your own code that extracts the ids from stream coming from `ls-tree`). Or you can use libgit2 to go through the tree and grab all the blobs from the trees recursively, which would end up getting you the same information in a slightly different way.

Then you can use some form of grep to run over these buffers. Your favourite programming language probably has an implementation of pcre or bindings to that library which you can feed these files.

You should be able to feed them one at a time regardless of which extraction method you choose by only reading from `cat-file` one at a time through those triplets that precede each object.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected libgit2 doesn't really provide what I need directly. I will most likely go with fetching the blobs using the library.